# hard disk problems (bad sectors)

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

I've a custom made project started in 2010 in which we have 10 computers in a factory running Ubuntu desktop, installed on a some-kind-of-portable-station-work.
In this time I've had 3 W.D. hard disks broken, in each laptop.

The computers are operating 24/7 and is not usual to shutdown or hibernate. Thus, the computers are moved in a portable-station-network while on.

Do you know any tools or maintenance procedures that should be made in order to minimize these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend switching to SSD's if you are not using them. In conditions where the laptops are moving around, SSDs will be less prone to failure. Small SSDs will usually be in the sub $100 range.

If your environment is very dusty, you should also have some sort of dust filter on your enclosure, although this can be kind of hard to do using laptops. You can always use Panasonic Toughbooks if you have a more extreme environment. They are made to handle desert storms, falls, water, etc. and are used by military personnel.

Answer (score 1):

HDDs commonly fail. I would recommend being gentle with them while they are spinning, and ensuring they're shut down (or asleep) before moving them around. Also, check out the SMART tools to detect when something is going wrong.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools